# Angular 2 Angucomplete Alt Directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to replace the [ng-tags-input](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) component with the [Angucomplete Alt](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt) component. The tags component uses a function to get search results from the string entered into the input box, and I was hoping to get angucomplete-alt to call the same function.

Here's the html template:

```
<div angucomplete-alt id="ex2"
     placeholder="Search..."
     pause="300"
     selected-object="selectedPerson"
     local-data="people"
     local-search="localSearch"
     title-field="firstName,surname"
     description-field="twitter"
     image-field="pic"
     minlength="1"
     input-class="form-control form-control-small"
     match-class="highlight">
</div>
```

What I was expecting is for the function localSearch() in the controller to be called whenever a character in entered into the input box with the character(s) as an argument.

But when a character is entered in angucomplete-alt's input box, it sends a GET request to localhost:3000/undefined + whatever the entered character is. Ie, if I enter 'f', it sends a request to http://localhost:3000/undefinedf

How can I call the function instead of sending a GET request. Or am I missing something in how this is supposed to work?

And if anyone has suggestions for a better autocomplete component, please say. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
`<input type="text" angucomplete-alt id="ex2" ... (keyup)="localSearch()" />`
```

Or you should try https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-auto-complete its working pretty cool for me.